# function call. Function cannot be called on possibly undefined value

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have the following react component

```
//@flow

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { submit } from 'redux-form';
import { Button } from 'ds-component-library';
import styles from './ApplicationLayout.scss';
import cs from 'classnames';

const RemoteSubmitButton = ({
  dispatch,
  form
}: {
  dispatch: void,
  form: string
}) =>
  <Button
    primary
    className={cs(styles['button-next'])}
    onClick={() => dispatch(submit(form))}
  >
    Next
  </Button>;

RemoteSubmitButton.displayName = 'RemoteSubmit';

export default connect()(RemoteSubmitButton);
```

I get the following error when running flow:

```
onClick={() => dispatch(submit(form))}
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function call. Function cannot be called on possibly undefined value
onClick={() => dispatch(submit(form))}
                        ^^^^^^^^ undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

The interpreter is not happy with the fact that you defined dispatch's type to be void when destructuring, it assumes it could possibly be undefined, but yet, you are always calling the function when the button is clicked.

A possible solution might be to extract the dispatch call to a function and check if dispatch is not undefined first.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the error message correctly, the problem might be that calling `submit(form)` might return `undefined` and that would cause a problem, because the `dispatch` function expects to be called wit one non-undefined argument.

Either `submit`'s annotations are wrong, or you need to check its return value before passing it to `dispatch`.